# No Adapter Attached: Skipping layout with Kotlin Framents

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to display items on a recyclerview but it says

> "No adapter attached; skipping layout"

.
I can't figure out the error. I tried with Activities instead of Fragements and it works super well. I am not yet so familiar with Framents. Kindly help.

**RecyclerAdapter**

```
package com.manzugerald.shukuruyesu.adapter

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.core.view.isVisible
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.manzugerald.shukuruyesu.HymnDetailActivity
import com.manzugerald.shukuruyesu.R
import com.manzugerald.shukuruyesu.model.Hymns


class HymnsItemAdapter(
    val context: Context,
    val dataset: List<Hymns>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<HymnsItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {


    //provide a reference to the views for each data item (in this case there is only one item)
    //Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    //you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    //Each data item is just an Affirmation object

    inner class ItemViewHolder(private val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        //val hymn_imageView: ImageView =view.findViewById(R.id.item_image)
        val hymn_title: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_hymn_title)
        val hymn_language: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_hymn_language)
        val hymn_number: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_hymn_number)
        var hymn_detail: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_hymn_text)

        //This has been unused. I will try to see how best to use it in the future
        var hymnPosition = 0

        /**
         * //So as the contents of the views displayed are clickable, append the setOnClickListener to the view holder rather than individual views
         * An explicit intent is used for exchanging information between two or more fragements or activities (screen)
         * The information to be carried to the next screen is passed as a key-value pair
         * The key is retrieved in the receiving activity or fragment
         * Then the data the key carries is gotten and assigned to the views so as to be viewed
         */


        init {
            view.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(context,HymnDetailActivity::class.java)
                val message = hymn_number.text.toString()
                val message_two = hymn_language.text.toString()
                val message_three = hymn_title.text.toString()
                val message_four = hymn_detail.text.toString()
                intent.putExtra("key_one", message)
                intent.putExtra("key_two",message_two)
                intent.putExtra("key_three",message_three)
                intent.putExtra("key_four",message_four)
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
     */

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
        val adapterLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_hymn_list, parent, false)
        return ItemViewHolder(adapterLayout)
    }

    /**
     * Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
     */

    /**
     * Binds or attaches data to the views.
     * Does this by interacting with the itemViewHolder
     */
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = dataset[position]

        //holder.hymn_imageView.setImageResource(item.imageResourceId)
        holder.hymn_title.text = context.resources.getString(item.titleStringResourceId)
        holder.hymn_language.text = context.resources.getString(item.languageStringResourceId)
        holder.hymn_number.text = "Song Number: " + context.resources.getString(item.numberStringResourceId)
        holder.hymn_detail.text = context.resources.getString(item.detailStringResourceId)
        holder.hymnPosition = position
        holder.hymn_detail.isVisible=false

    }

    /**
     * Return the size of the dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
     */

    //Takes not of the size of the data, number of rows so that binding can be done with ease
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = dataset.size
}
```

**The data source:**

```
package com.manzugerald.shukuruyesu.data

import com.manzugerald.shukuruyesu.R
import com.manzugerald.shukuruyesu.model.Hymns

class HymnsDataSource {

    //Gets the data from the string resources
    fun loadHymns():List<Hymns>{
        return listOf<Hymns>(
            Hymns(R.string.affirmation1,R.string.affirmationNum1,R.string.affirmationLang1,R.string.affirmationDetail1),
            Hymns(R.string.affirmation2,R.string.affirmationNum2,R.string.affirmationLang2,R.string.affirmationDetail2),
            Hymns(R.string.affirmation3,R.string.affirmationNum3,R.string.affirmationLang3,R.string.affirmationDetail3),
            Hymns(R.string.affirmation4,R.string.affirmationNum4,R.string.affirmationLang4,R.string.affirmationDetail4),
            Hymns(R.string.affirmation5,R.string.affirmationNum5,R.string.affirmationLang5,R.string.affirmationDetail5),
            Hymns(R.string.affirmation6,R.string.affirmationNum6,R.string.affirmationLang6,R.string.affirmationDetail6),
            Hymns(R.string.affirmation7,R.string.affirmationNum7,R.string.affirmationLang7,R.string.affirmationDetail7),
            Hymns(R.string.affirmation8,R.string.affirmationNum8,R.string.affirmationLang8,R.string.affirmationDetail8),
            Hymns(R.string.affirmation9,R.string.affirmationNum9,R.string.affirmationLang9,R.string.affirmationDetail9),
            Hymns(R.string.affirmation10,R.string.affirmationNum10,R.string.affirmationLang10,R.string.affirmationDetail10)
        )
    }
}
```

**The Data class:**

```
package com.manzugerald.shukuruyesu.model

import androidx.annotation.DrawableRes
import androidx.annotation.StringRes

    data class Hymns(
    
        @StringRes var titleStringResourceId: Int,
        @StringRes var numberStringResourceId: Int,
        @StringRes var languageStringResourceId: Int,
        @StringRes var detailStringResourceId: Int
       // @DrawableRes val imageResourceId: Int
    
    )
```

**The Fragment to display the recyclerview:**

```
package com.manzugerald.shukuruyesu

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.manzugerald.shukuruyesu.data.HymnsDataSource
import com.manzugerald.shukuruyesu.databinding.FragmentHymnListBinding
import com.manzugerald.shukuruyesu.adapter.HymnsItemAdapter
import com.manzugerald.shukuruyesu.model.Hymns

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Use the [HymnListFragment.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class HymnListFragment : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    //enable and refrence binding
    private var _binding: FragmentHymnListBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    //property for the recycler view
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    }

    //To inflate the layout, call teh onCreatView Method
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentHymnListBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        val view = binding.root
        return view
    }

    //Bind the views in onViewCreated
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        val myDataSource = HymnsDataSource().loadHymns()
        recyclerView = binding.recyclerView
        recyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            adapter= HymnsItemAdapter(dataset = myDataSource, context = requireContext())
            adapter= HymnsItemAdapter(context,myDataSource)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding=null
    }
}
```

**HymnListFragment Layout File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HymnListFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_View"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item_hymn_list"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you include your HymnListFragment layout file?

Comment: @HenryTwist, sorry for responding late. I've edited and included the HymnListFragment layout File

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution to the question...
Neither the Adapter nor the Fragments had a problem.
The problem was in my MainActivity.kt file, which I didn't upload here...
The error came about when I tried changing from activities to Fragments....

Initially, I forgot to take off or comment the inflation of the layouts (Layouts are inflated in the respective Fragments, not the main activity).
For illustration purposes, I will comment the said error in the code.
My bad!

**Main Activity class:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```